# Javascript stream to file

Tags: javascript

My text-to-speech software will generate sound on client side.

1. How to allow the user to download the generated sound stored in an ArrayBuffer?
2. Also, if the total generated data is large than I wan't to stream it to hard-disk rather than storing it in RAM. Is it possible?

Comment: You can't write to disk from a client script, unless you're using Node as a desktop application.

Comment: You can save to localstorage or IndexDB if the object becomes too big

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save a big object temporarily to disk you can either use localStorage or IndexDB. See here an example how to save blob to [localStoarge](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/saving-images-and-files-in-localstorage/) (example use image but can be applied to any format see the "Using blob as responseType" part).
To allow the user download it you can save with [createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL).

```
function download(content, fileName, contentType) {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    var file = new Blob([content], {type: contentType});
    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    a.download = fileName;
    a.click();
}

download(arrayBuffer, 'media.mp3', 'audio/mpeg');
```

Of course use the appropriate format.